# Alternative reference for number of restricted partitions

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

I am looking for the number of partitions of some number $n$ into $k$ parts. Following the [Wikipedia article on partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), I ended up with Andrew's book [1]. Judging by [Google's preview](http://books.google.de/books?id=Sp7z9sK7RNkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q&f=false) Chapter 3 seems to contain information about what I need; unfortunately, the preview contains only one page of that chapter. Our library does not have a copy available either.

Even though [there may not be an answer for me there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240427/partitions-of-an-integer-into-k-parts/241797#241797) I'd like to check available results. Since I can not access the reference list of said chapter: which papers is Andrew's chapter based upon?

Are there other (newer?) books or articles that contain relevant information?

---

1. The Theory of Partitions by George E. Andrews (1976)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\partition}[2]{\genfrac{\lvert}{\rvert}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}$
I was not able to track down Andrew's references yet, but I found the following.

Knuth [1, p399] gives as ordinary generating function

$\qquad\displaystyle \sum_{n \geq 0}\ \partition{n}{k} 
  = \frac{z^k}{(1-z)(1-z^2) \cdot \dots \cdot (1-z^k)}$

where $\partition{n}{k}$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into (exactly) $k$ parts.

Flajolet/Sedgewick [2, p47] give the asymptotic

$\qquad\displaystyle [z^n]\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-z^2) \cdot \dots \cdot (1-z^k)}
  \sim \frac{n^{k-1}}{k!(k-1)!}$,

for the number of partitions of $n$ with *at most* $k$ parts.

Put together, this gives

$\qquad\displaystyle \partition{n}{k} \sim \frac{(n-k)^{k-1}}{k!(k-1)!}$;

this [may be the best known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240427/partitions-of-an-integer-into-k-parts/241797#241797).

---

1. [The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4A](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html) by D. E. Knuth (2011)
2. [Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/AnaCombi/anacombi.html) by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick (2009)

Answer (score 0):

In case you're a constructivist, a useful and widely known recursion exists:
 p(n,k)=p(n,k-1)+p(n-k,k) with p(n,0)=0 and p(0,k)=1.

Comment: Thanks, but it does -- unfortunately -- not help me. (The recurrence is, of course, given in TAoCP, by the way)